# Merge two folder (update file no overwrite), command line

Tags: bash, git, merge

I've got two folder: provided and done. At start done is made by copying provided and then i've made some changes in done (implementing some functions). Then comes an update in provided: some functions in existing files are added and there is some new files too

I want to merge theses two folder (provided into done):

- new files must by copied
- existing files must be updated (as in a git merge, appending only what is new) -- this is the hard part

Is there any existing command (for linux) that can achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

> git merge-file `current-file` `base-file` `other-file`

git merge-file incorporates all changes that lead from the base-file to `other-file` into `current-file`. The result ordinarily goes into `current-file`.

Comment: This is kind of what i'm looking for, thank's. Do u know if conflict can happen if other-file and base-file are the same?
And moreover have u any idea how i could combine command to do it on all file in a floder? i'm not very used to combining commands